# "ng build --prod" gives <full_correct_path_to_my_file> "is missing from the Typescript compilation"

Tags: angular, angular-cli

This problem has kept me from getting any work done for 4 hours straight now.

The title almost says it all. I have a Typescript file located at `src/generated/ppo-datatypes/ppo-datatypes.d.ts` (usually generated by a Maven plugin, but I'm now bypassing Maven and invoking `ng build --prod` directly).

The debug build with `ng build` (without `--prod`) works ok, but no matter what I try, I can't get the production build to work. My `tsconfig.json` explicitly specifies the path to my file with a wildcard, like this (note that I've also tried the direct path without any wildcards):

```
"include": [
    <...proprietary modules omitted...>,
    "./src/generated/**/*.ts",
    "./src/polyfills.ts",
    "./src/main.ts"
]
```

We have a deployment date coming up soon, so I have to find a solution to this. I consider removing the `--prod` to be an absolute last resort.

Comment: Quick search shows a lot of people saying there's a typo or case difference in a file/directory/import. Did this start out of nowhere? `git bisect` maybe?

Comment: @phix It might have been present ever since I introduced this generated file. Its filename and path are all lower-case. And the problem only exists with the prod build flag.

Comment: Try putting it in `files` of tsconfig? Just shooting from the hip here.

Comment: Tried that too.

Comment: I'd suggest combing through your imports and making sure the paths are correct (case included). Every question I've seen with this error points to that.

Comment: @Phix Done that - in fact I had the path aliased in the tsconfig.json until today, but have now replaced all aliased occurrences with the full path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184495/discussion-between-phix-and-jpnotadragon).